# Why is the output displaying memory code?

Tags: python, regex, memory, subprocess, output

I am trying to isolate the MAC Address from the `ifconfig` command but the output is displaying what I believe is memory code. I am running python 2.7 on a VB Kali.

```
root@osboxes:~# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.22  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::1171:bf6a:17f8:972  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:f8:15:03  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2593  bytes 3769210 (3.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 794  bytes 57174 (55.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import re


def mac_1(network):
    output_check = subprocess.check_output(['ifconfig', network])
    re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", output_check)
    # print(output_check)


print('[+] MAC Address is ' + str(mac_1))
```

Output Code:

```
/root/PycharmProjects/test001/venv/bin/python /root/PycharmProjects/test001/test001.py
[+] MAC Address is <function mac_1 at 0x7ff4ed70e3b0>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `str(mac_1)`, mac_1 is a function so it's printing the location of that function in memory.

Comment: call `str(mac_1, 'eth0')` instead

Comment: `mac_1()` doesn't return anything. What are you expecting it to print?

Comment: @samthegolden You mean `str(mac_1('eth0'))`

Comment: yes @Barmar my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure this out a few days ago and haven't had time to respond. Here is the result that I was looking for:

Input

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import re

output_check = subprocess.check_output(['ifconfig'])
check = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", output_check)

print("Mac Address is: " + check.group(0))
```

Output

```
Mac Address is: 08:69:18:f9:85:06
```

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

`str(mac_1)`, mac_1 is a function so it's printing the location of that function in memory. You need to call it with an argument as you specified in the definition:

```
def mac_1(network):  # network is the argument
```

The `mac_1` function also doesn't have a return type, so even if you called it with an argument it will just print `None`. So you need to return the output of your search.

Though I might suggest just using a different [netifaces](https://pypi.org/project/netifaces/). Then it's as simple as

```
>>> addrs = netifaces.ifaddresses('eth0')
>>> addrs[netifaces.AF_LINK]
[{'addr': '00:12:34:56:78:9a'}]
```